# Enterprises List Call is not available in Android Management API how to implement it in my EMM Console?

Tags: android-management-api

It Says
"This feature is not generally available yet. Lists enterprises that are managed by an EMM. Only partial views are returned."
But i want the list of enterprise to be displayed in my emm console
for more details you can refer here:
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises/list

when i try the same call in the API Explorer it says:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid request",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

Answer (score 1):

The enterprise.list API is part of the upcoming “[Programmatic Enterprise Creation](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/10432944?hl=en&ref_topic=10431722)” feature, which is not yet generally available. The library includes the API calls needed to integrate this upcoming feature into your solution ahead of the feature’s release. Until the feature is released, the error message you are receiving is the expected response from this API.

The current process to create an enterprise requires keeping track of the enterprise id returned as part of the enterprise creation process.  As such, there is no current mechanism available that will allow you to obtain a list of enterprises to display within your EMM console.